# Keep a single element in dataframe of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
  Movement Distance     Speed   Delay    Loss
0   [1, 1]   [1, 1]  [25, 25]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]
1   [1, 1]   [1, 1]  [25, 25]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]
2   [1, 1]   [1, 1]  [25, 25]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]
3   [1, 1]   [1, 1]  [25, 25]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]
4   [1, 1]   [1, 1]  [25, 25]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]
```

How can I remove all but the first element in each column and then unlist so the dataframe becomes like this:

```
  Movement Distance     Speed   Delay    Loss
0   1      1            25      0        0
1   1      1            25      0        0
2   1      1            25      0        0
3   1      1            25      0        0
4   1      1            25      0        0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) or indexing equivalently as:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str[0], downcast='integer', errors='ignore'))
```

Or if the data is already clean, we have [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) new in pandas 1.0 (thanks cs95):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str[0]).convert_dtypes()

   Movement  Distance  Speed  Delay  Loss
0         1         1     25      0     0
1         1         1     25      0     0
2         1         1     25      0     0
3         1         1     25      0     0
4         1         1     25      0     0
```